# mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set

Tags: php, email, xampp

I am new to PHP and currently i am playing around with user registration module for an e-commerce site, where user can register and get acknowledge mail to activate their account for the application. I installed SMTP on my Windows 7 machine. When i register a new user through application it should send a mail to user mail address which i am not getting. The application is running locally on XAMPP.

```
$body = "Thank you for registering at <whatever site>. To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
$body .= BASE_URL . 'activate.php?x=' . urlencode($e) . "&y=$a";
mail($trimmed['email'], 'Registration Confirmation', $body, 'From: admin@sitename.com');
```

I am not sure that i should deploy application on any other machine or it should even work even with SMTP and application running locally.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Running both, the http server (so the app) and an smtp on a local system is no issue. The error message simply says that the smtp server either does not run or is blocked somehow.

Comment: Yeah true i restarted SMTP server and tried again and this time i am getting 
mail(): SMTP server response: 550 Invalid recipient: error when sending a mail to my gmail account.

Comment: This now looks like the internal filtering that protect your smtp server getting used as an open mail relay (read: spam source). Typically smtp servers are configured such that they only accept two types of messages: from an "inside" email address (where domains considered "inside" have to be configured) or from an "outside" address, when targeted to an "inside" address. Everything else is blocked as "relaying attempt". You want to keep it that way, but configure your internal domains.